# How expensive is call of Class.isAnnotationPresent(...)?

Tags: java, android, performance, reflection, annotations

I'm wondering how expensive this operation can be on following runtimes:

- JVM8
- Dalvik
- ART

The information about annotations of given class (target=TYPE) is available in compile time, so I'd guess that it can be cached somehow. But on the other hand, I've heard Dalvik had quite poor performance regarding annotations.

If I can check and cache the info during compile time (with some code generating plugin), should I do it, or would it be overoptimization?

Comment: How much, or rather, how often do you need to call this?

Comment: Let's say it would be called during view recycling in RecyclerView/ListView. But I'd like to know how costly it is relatively - is it like a method call or more like a new instance creation via reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skimming the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29), it looks like `isAnnotationPresent(...)` calls `getAnnotation(...)`, which calls `initAnnotationsIfNecessary()`.

`initAnnotationsIfNecessary()` constructs a map of annotations the first time it is called; the previously-constructed map is reused on subsequent calls.

So, by the looks of it, the first call is expensive (-ish); the subsequent calls are pretty cheap.

Comment: Ok, so it's not compile time. I've checked sources on Android and it looks like it doesn't even have runtime cache. I didn't digged deeper into annotation extracting, but it seems expensive.